# Binding DataGrid with dataset and set columns width

Tags: asp.net

I have DataGrid, this datagrid has a binding with a dataset

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="myGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyField1" HeaderText="MyField1"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyField2" HeaderText="MyField2"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>                
</asp:DataGrid>

myGrid.DataSource = GetMyDataset();
myGrid.DataBind();
```

That's work but I see has column all the fields of my dataset + the 2 columns defined. 
I'd like see only the columns.

And how set the column width % ?

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Try this

From ASPX page

```
 <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 </asp:DataGrid>
```

From Code Behind

```
 myGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
 myGrid.DataSource = GetMyDataset();
 myGrid.DataBind();
```

Read more about `AutoGenerateColumns` @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)

**Update**

To set the width of column, you can

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyField1" HeaderText="MyField1"
    ItemStyle-Width="30%">
</asp:BoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

add AutoGenerateColums="false" to the datagrid tag.

Your updated code would be

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyField1" HeaderText="MyField1"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyField2" HeaderText="MyField2"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>                
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: OK thanks :). One more question, how set in % the columns width ?

Answer (score 0):

Put  AutoGenerateColumns="false" in the grid.

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```